# interaction of mathematical structures (rephrased)

Tags: mathematical-physics, black-holes

From a physicist's perspective there are several situations in which somehow arbitrary choices of mathematical structures can be made. One can describe a system from different perspectives, etc. without changing anything in the physical properties. (see gauge invariance, picture changing etc.)
In the situation when these choices impose a mathematical structure one has limitations in the subsequent choices (are these limitations physical???). However, there are situations when this prescription does not hold. The best example is in this case the Black-Hole complementarity principle (if it is well defined in the first place). 
So, the question about how mathematical structures "interact" in a logical way is not a bad one. Again: what is the interaction between, say, locality and Hausdorff-ity in the case of a black hole? Or what is the true relation between metrizability and hausdorff-ity of a space in the context of a black hole? The question about how mathematical structures assigned (innocently) at some point interact in different situations is in my opinion a quite relevant one...

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96490/2451

Comment: Hi user33923. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.